# Could I pass a parameter to a CTE from SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing, common-table-expression

I have the following VIEW on my data server

```
CREATE VIEW [test_view] AS
    EpicActual (EpicID, Actual) AS
    (
        SELECT
            I.EpicID,
            CAST(WL.timeworked / 3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
        FROM TasksTable ST
        INNER JOIN IssuesTable I ON I.ID = ST.IssueID
        INNER JOIN worklog WL ON WL.issueid = ST.ID
    ),

    SELECT 
        ISNULL(A.Actual, 0) + CAST(ISNULL(E.TIMESPENT, 0) / 3600 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) [TotalActual],
        E.PROJECT,
        E.REPORTER,
        E.ASSIGNEE

    FROM jiraissue E 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EpicActual A ON A.EpicID = E.ID
    WHERE E.issuetype = 6
GO
```

The "EpicActual" CTE uses the worklog table, which is the amount of work for the issue. The worklog table contains a CreatedDate.

an SSRS report uses this view to create a report. It also contains a parameter named "CreatedAfter", which is supposed to be used to obtain worklog entries created after this date. I was wondering if it's possible to add this to the CTE? (e.g. add something like "WHERE WL.CreatedDate >= @CreatedAfter" in the query of the CTE).

Comment: A view can't have a parameter, tho. If you use the query for the view as the query (instead of the view) for the SSRS dataset, then the parameter should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the join to

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM EpicActual WHERE CreatedDate >= @CreatedAfter) A 
        ON A.EpicID = E.ID
```

This way it will not matter if EpicActual is a view or CTE although performance might not be great...